# Replace string everywhere except if its within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, quotes

I would like to replace all `:)` by `:D`, except if they are within quotes `"`

Example 1:

```
Hey man :D, how're you? :) My friend told me "this can't be true :)"
```

becomes

```
Hey man :D, how're you? :D My friend told me "this can't be true :)"
```

As you see, `:)` is not replaced if it's enclosed by `"`. If this condition wouldn't be there, it would be quite simple, right? I am using Javascript (jQuery) for all this.

If this is not plainly possible with a regex, what would be an alternate suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming no double quote is unbalanced, this is the regex that should work for you:

```
:\)(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

**Explanation:** This regex is using a positive lookahead that basically is matching 0 or more occurrences of a pair of `some text until a double quote is found` i.e. `([^"]*"){2}` on the right hand side (RHS) of every match of `:)`.

Which in simple term means replace a `:)` only if it is outside double quotes since all the matches inside double quotes will have odd number of `[^"]*"` matches on RHS.

#### Live Demo: 1. http://www.rubular.com/r/3aixZy5bYR

#### Live Demo: 2. http://ideone.com/C679NW

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseSmiley(str){
    return str.replace(/(?!"):\)(?!")/g, ":D");
}

console.log(parseSmiley('Hey man :D, how\'re you? :) My friend told me "this can\'t be true :)"');
```

[And the fiddle with an input so you can test](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8v4D/).

Basically, we just replace all instances of `:)` not encased in `" "` with `:D`

Comment: This won't work. Test your regex with `Hey man :D, how\'re you? :) My friend told me "this can\'t be true :) ..."`

Answer (score 0):

If you need variables to control of this - then you could try

```
function doReplace(find, repl, str, fullWordsOnly, ignoreSQuotes,  ignoreDQuotes, caseSensitive) {
   if (caseSensitive == undefined) caseSensitive = false;

   var flags = 'gm';
   if (!caseSensitive) flags += 'i';

   var control = escapeRegExp(find);
   if (ignoreDQuotes) control = '(?!\\B"[^"]*)' + control + '(?![^"]*"\\B)';
   if (ignoreSQuotes) control = '(?!\\B\'[^\']*)' + control + '(?![^\']*\'\\B)';
   if (fullWordsOnly) control = '\\b' + control + '\\b';

   return str.replace(new RegExp(control, flags), repl);

}
```

Note, this will probably have problems with single quotes when using abbreviated words such as how're and can't, so I've also included a hack to fix against that:

```
// Fix any abbreviated words ('re or 't) 
str=str.replace(/'re\/b/gi, '&apos;re');
str=str.replace(/'t\b/gi, '&apos;t');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/ct7vayz5/4/ for a working demo