# How to replace a string which is not in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, quotes

im struggling with the following scenario, i have a multiline string which has the word test multiple times inside, the string is:

```
Hello my name is "test" im a test
test is testing
```

i need to replace all the test -strings which are not in quotes
every of the found ones should be followed by at least 1 whitespace OR a linebreak not by anything else, so the above string would transform into:

```
Hello my name is "test" im a HELLOWORLD
HELLOWORLD is testing
```

also the test -string could be prepended by whitespaces, but not also without.

What i already found out is a method to only replace a string which is not inside of quotes:

```
str.replace(/(test)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)/, 'HELLOWORLD')
```

could sombebody give me a hand with finding the other rules?

Comment: i would also like to include single-quotes, so neither "test" nor 'test' would get replaced

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741243/replace-string-everywhere-except-if-its-within-quotes/69428257#69428257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str = 'Hello my \'test\' name is "test" im a test\ntest is testing';
var repl = str.replace(/("[^"]*"|'[^']*')|\btest\b/g, function($0, $1) { 
           return ($1 == undefined) ? "HELLOWORLD" : $1; });
```

**Output:**

```
Hello my 'test' name is "test" im a HELLOWORLD
HELLOWORLD is testing
```

Comment: does not work as expected because 'another' would get replaced with HELLOWORLD

Comment: That's not correct, have you tried given code in answer. As you can see `'test'`  remains unchanged above.

Comment: im sorry, you are right, it works. I just copied the regex pattern and replaced it in my code ad there it didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

```
(\btest\b)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/28

Comment: this one does also replace test -strings inside of single quotes