# How to replace a string which is not in id="*"?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, quotes

Is there a way to replace a string which is not in `id="<any_characters>"`?

I only found this [How to replace a string which is not in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170998/how-to-replace-a-string-which-is-not-in-quotes) which doesn't replace a string in quotes.

```
(\btest\b)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

However, I want that the string can be replaced in quotes like **"replace"** but **id="don't replace"** shouldn't be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be:

```
id="[^"]+"|(replace)
# id = "..." or replace
```

---

Additionally, you'll need some programming logic here:

```js
var subject = '"replace" but id="don\'t replace" some lorem ipsum';
var regex = /id="[^"]+"|(replace)/g;

replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (typeof(group1) == 'undefined') return m;
    else return "some other string here";
});
console.log(replaced);
```

---

The idea here is to *match* `id="..."` but not to *capture* it. The only occurrences of `replace` will be captured outside of `id="..."`. In languages with `PCRE` support, this can be achieved via `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` directly in the expression but `JavaScript` lacks support thereof.

Comment: Hmm, i wanted to use the pattern with the programming language Dart. Unfortunately, there is no method which supports functions like you used with replace(regex, function(m, group1)) . Is there any other way without the use of functions as a second argument or only to use regex patterns?

Comment: Nice answer. If you want to capture escaped double quotes in strings you can use `id="(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|(replace)` (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes)) +1

Comment: @GreenTigerEye: I am by now means an expert in `dart` - maybe they support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` ? https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/RegExp-class.html But honestly, I doubt it.